# How to load projects in GitHub

Tags: github

I created a small project with Web APIs, SQL Server code and C# MVC code on my local machine.
  How do I load that code on a GitHub repository (I just created an account) to show to others?
 Can someone guide me?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/

Comment: Short version: `git init; git add .; git commit -m "Initial commit."; git remote add origin git@github.com:my-username/my-repo.git;git push origin master`. Be aware this will commit any sensitive info in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install git and get that going, create a new project in github, then in your projects folder run:

```
git init
git remote add origin "git@github.com:my-username/my-repo.git" 
git add .
git commit -m"Initial Commit"
git push origin master
```

And your code should be up there

Answer (score 0):

Go to github.com to your repositories section.
Create [new repository there](https://github.com/new).

After do clone from there using nice green button on right top corner or with

```
git clone https://github.com/<your_nick>/<your_repository>.git
```

(don't forget to install [git client](https://git-scm.com/downloads) on your machine before clone)

If you not familiar with git commands yet - you can use [SourceThree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) as client.